# Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler VS10 Addin

Tags: c#, .net, performance, redgate, ants

I've installed and activated the ANTS Performance Profiler 7, but I can't see the Addin in Visual Studio 2010 on the menu bar.

If I open the Addin-Manager in VS10 (Tools->Addin-Manager), I can see the addin, but not in the menu bar. I've reinstalled it, but no effect.

Does somebody have an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the menu bar, select Customize and choose the menu bar "ANTS". There should be five commands: Profile Memory, Profile Performance, Launch ANTS Performance Profiler, Launch ANTS Memory Profiler, and About ANTS Profiler.

If you don't see those, maybe the add-in is not set to load at start in the add-in manager.

Comment: I can't see the Profiler in the customize menu bar and I've set the add-in to load at start in the add-in manager.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a prior problem with an add-in, VS renames it to a file with a _addin extension. Can you find C:\Program Files\Red Gate\ANTS Profiler Visual Studio Add-in 1 and make sure you have a file called  RedGate.ANTSVsAddin.addin.

Comment: Hi Wonko. I've found the files: RedGate.ANTSVsAddin.addin and RedGate.ANTSVsAddin.dll in that folder

Comment: Beyond this I would say it's an environment-specific problem. You can try running devenv "as administrator" or try devenv /reset. The latter will reset all add-ins just so you know.